# installing ubuntu alongside windows vista failed

Tags: dual-boot, windows-vista

I installed Ubuntu on a external (removable) drive alongside Window Vista, the install procedure did not give the option to install on the internal drive.
After rebooting the screen stayed black, I did not get a choice menu for Windows or Ubuntu. I booted the try version from the Ubuntu install dvd and was able to run Boot Repair. It gave the message that it was repaired and that I should no define the external drive as boot drive. If I do that the screen stays black. If I boot the default way Windows now boots fine. But how can I boot Ubuntu from the external drive? My internal drive is unshrinkable. The external drive has two 125gb partitions: the original shrunken one and the one made by Ubuntu installer.

The Boot Repair specified this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15580533/

Thanks 
Jos

Comment: Why is the internal partition unsrinkable?

Comment: When the external hard drive is disconnected then the installer does not give the option to install alongside Windows. I assume that it cannot resize the factory installed Windows partition. Actually in Windows with Storage Management I have the option to shrink it, but only free 15GB of the the 285GB.

Comment: you can shrink it, but it seems Ubuntu isn't showing you because you only have 15GB free space at the end of the partition. Can you open up Computer or My Computer in Windows and tell me how much free space it says the drive has?

Comment: The internal drive has 74,2GB free space. I have read there was an issue with factory installed windows drives having an unmovable file near the end of the partition.

Comment: Well what you can try to do is defragment the drive.

Comment: I did that first of all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I used the ¨Do something else¨ option and followed the tutorial at http://linuxbsdos.com/2013/10/23/how-to-install-ubuntu-13-10-on-an-external-hard-drive/